# Присвоить min к заведомо несуществующему значению индекса в массиве?

Tags: java

Подскажите, как присвоить min к заведомо несуществующему значению индекса в массиве (Java)?

Comment: Наверное, `-1`должно подойти...

Comment: а если массив с отрицательными и положительными значениями?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы именно к несуществующему индексу, если делаю х[-1], то программа не работает

Comment: Вот не я написал про значение ИНДЕКСА. А индекс у массива - он всегда целый непрерывный от нуля и выше. Или мы про разные Java говорим? или про разные массивы?